# How to show .tiff file on openlayer map on specific coordinates in angular or js?

Tags: angular, openlayers, tiff, geotiff, openlayers-6

I have a tiff file and I want to show that tiff file on the Openlayer map on its respective coordinates. I tried many ways on youtube but could not find a proper way to show the tiff file on OpenLayers. Kindly give a code snippet or proper way so that I can show the tiff file on the OpenLayers map. I am using angular and opanlayer.

Comment: Is the file a simple tiff image or a GeoTIFF file?

Comment: simple tiff image

Comment: You would need to display it as an ImageStatic and use a custom loader and third party utility to decode it https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-1mc3xb?file=/main.js

Comment: thanks for your answer one more question it is possible to overlay tiff file on openlayer beacuse tiff file is of specific coordinataes and i want to show this tiff file on map with respective coordinaties.

Comment: Yes, if you know the coordinates and projection, as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html